# Using IISProxy.dll with 2 IIS applications

Tags: iis-7, weblogic

I have setup 2 iis7 servers that have the identical configuration. Both servers send requests to the same weblogic server with the same IP:Port. I am using IISProxy.dll to load balance the server. The iisproxy.ini is the same on both servers. Now I am unsure about the following: Lets say iis server 1 receives a requests and routes it to weblogic1 and iis server 2 receives a request as well and routes it also to weblogic1, then will the request fail because both iis servers are routing the request to the same weblogic1 server? I am not sure if I explained it well. I am a new to routing and load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic can handle **many** requests at a time. Thats a **basic feature** of a web server and/or an app server.

From your scenario, two separate requests are going from IIS to the same Weblogic, but that will just be treated as two clients from Weblogic's point of view.